# How to reformat specific data from json with jq

Tags: json, jq, reformat

I'm new to json and want to extract data (blocks) from a specific json. I've tried to find information on how to do this with jq but so far I cannot seem to get what I want.

My json:

```
{
   "now" : 1589987097.9,
   "aircraft" : [
      {
         "mlat" : [],
         "rssi" : -26.2,
         "track" : 319,
         "speed" : 354,
         "messages" : 16,
         "seen" : 0.7,
         "altitude" : 38000,
         "vert_rate" : 0,
         "hex" : "44b5b4",
         "tisb" : []
      },
      {
         "squawk" : "6220",
         "altitude" : 675,
         "seen" : 1.1,
         "messages" : 7220,
         "tisb" : [],
         "hex" : "484a95",
         "mlat" : [],
         "rssi" : -22
      },
      {
         "hex" : "484846",
         "tisb" : [],
         "messages" : 20,
         "speed" : 89,
         "seen" : 0.4,
         "squawk" : "7000",
         "altitude" : 500,
         "rssi" : -23.7,
         "track" : 185,
         "mlat" : []
      },
      {
         "category" : "B1",
         "mlat" : [],
         "rssi" : -24.3,
         "flight" : "ZSGBX   ",
         "altitude" : 3050,
         "squawk" : "7000",
         "seen" : 16.8,
         "messages" : 37,
         "tisb" : [],
         "hex" : "00901a"
      }
 ],
   "messages" : 35857757
}
```

I would like to reformat this json to *only* include 'blocks' that contain specific hex values.

So for example, I want I would like my output to contain 44b5b4 and 00901a:

```
{
   "now" : 1589987097.9,
   "aircraft" : [
      {
         "mlat" : [],
         "rssi" : -26.2,
         "track" : 319,
         "speed" : 354,
         "messages" : 16,
         "seen" : 0.7,
         "altitude" : 38000,
         "vert_rate" : 0,
         "hex" : "44b5b4",
         "tisb" : []
      },
      {
         "category" : "B1",
         "mlat" : [],
         "rssi" : -24.3,
         "flight" : "ZSGBX   ",
         "altitude" : 3050,
         "squawk" : "7000",
         "seen" : 16.8,
         "messages" : 37,
         "tisb" : [],
         "hex" : "00901a"
      }
 ],
   "messages" : 35857757
}
```

Can someone tell me how to remove all items not having those 2 hex identifiers but still keep the same json structure?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Select *blocks* whose `hex` matches one of the specific values and update `aircraft` to leave only those.

```
.aircraft |= map(select(.hex | IN("44b5b4", "00901a")))
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/TVRZW2Of_P)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Do a `select()` on the array `aircraft`, matching only the required hex values. The `map()` function takes input the entire array and the result of the select operation i.e. filtering of objects based on the `.hex` value is updated back `|=` to the original array and the rest of the fields are kept intact.

```
jq '.aircraft |= map(select(.hex == "44b5b4" or .hex == "00901a"))' json
```